# Showing that two representations with 'isomorphic' direct sum decomposition are equivalent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, direct-sum

I'm trying to prove that if 2 complex representations have the same character, then they are the same. In my proof, I found that is sufficient that the following statement is true:

> Let $\rho, \tau$ be representations such that: $$\begin{cases}\rho =
>  \rho_1 \oplus \rho_2 \\ \tau = \tau_1 \oplus \tau_2 \\\rho_1 \cong
>  \tau_1 \\\rho_2 \cong \tau_2\end{cases}$$ Then $\rho \cong \tau$

I tried using the definition of isomorphic complex representations to obtain this result, but I was unsuccesful. Please keep the proofs elementary. Thank you.

Comment: Are you working with representations as homomorphisms to some general linear group?  Or are you working with modules over the group algebra?

Comment: Representations as homomorphisms between finite groups and groups of automorphisms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V, V_i, W, W_i$ be vector spaces so that
$$\rho\colon G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$$
$$\rho_i\colon G \to \mathrm{GL}(V_i)$$
$$\tau\colon G \to \mathrm{GL}(W)$$
$$\tau_i\colon G \to \mathrm{GL}(W_i)$$
are the representations that you're looking at.  Now to say that $\rho \simeq \rho_1 \oplus \rho_2$ means there is an isomorphism $\phi\colon V \to V_1 \oplus V_2$ such that if $\phi(v) = (v_1, v_2)$ then $\phi(\rho(g)(v)) = (\rho_1(g)(v_1), \rho_2(g)(v_2))$.  Similarly $\tau \simeq \tau_1 \oplus \tau_2$ means there's an isomorphism $\psi\colon W \to W_1 \oplus W_2$ with a similar property.  That $\rho_i \simeq \tau_i$ means there's an isomorphism $\sigma_i\colon V_i \to W_i$ such that $\sigma_i(\rho_i(g)(v)) = \tau_i(g)(\sigma_i(v))$.

All I've done so far is expand the definition of an isomorphism of representations so that everything has a name.  Now the map you want is
$$V \overset{\phi}{\to} V_1 \oplus V_2 \overset{\sigma_1 \oplus\sigma_2}{\to} W_1 \oplus W_2 \overset{\psi^{-1}}{\to} W.$$
You'll need to check that this is an isomorphism of vector spaces and that it has the required properties to be a map between the representations $\rho$ and $\tau$.

Comment: Isn't the definition that there exists a vector space isomorphism f such that $\rho_g = f \circ \tau_g \circ f^{-1}$ for all g?

Comment: Taking your definition and precomposing with $f$ gives $\rho_g\circ f = f\circ\tau_g$, which is what I've been using.

Comment: Okay thank you. I actually wrote that $\rho = \rho_1 \oplus \rho_2$ and not that they are isomorphic (yes I know equality implies this), but can't your argument be simplified using this?

Comment: If that's the case then $\sigma_1\oplus\sigma_2$ is the isomorphism you want.